# RavenDB 2.5 failover server setup

Tags: c#, ravendb, failover

We are using RavenDB 2.5 and need to set failover connection detail in our C# solution. I found the document that explains how to do this here,
http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/bundles/how-client-integrates-with-replication-bundle#failover-servers

but there is no failover servers property of IDocumentStore in version 2.5.

How to set failover connection details in C# Raven client?

Comment: The doc you referenced is for 3.0.  If you need to run 2.5, the reference is here: http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/csharp/server/scaling-out/replication

Answer (score 0):

In 2.5, you need to create you own `ReplicationInformer` class that has a default, although note that it is usually much easier to just call: `ReplicationInformerLocalCache.TrySavingReplicationInformationToLocalCache` with the destinations of your choice.

https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/blob/2.5/Raven.Client.WinRT/Connection/ReplicationInformerLocalCache.cs#L49